# Draw arrows between 3 points

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to draw arrows between three points in matplotlib.

Let's assume we have 3 arbitrary points (A1,A2,A3) in 2d and we want to draw arrows from A1 to A2 and from A2 to A3.

Some code to make it clear:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A1=np.array([10,23])
A2=np.array([20,30])
A3=np.array([45,78])
drawArrow(A1,A2);
drawArrow(A2,A3);
plt.show();
```

How can we write a function drawArrow(tailCoord,headCoord) that receives the coordinates of the tail and the head of an arrow and plots it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have further special requirements for your desired method, you can use [pyplot's arrow function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.arrow), e.g.:

```
def drawArrow(A, B):
    plt.arrow(A[0], A[1], B[0] - A[0], B[1] - A[1],
              head_width=3, length_includes_head=True)
```

The API mentions some more keyword arguments; yet more style options can be found in [the API for FancyArrow](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrow) (which is what arrow actually creates under the hood).

Note that the arrows might be off-plot, as apparently pyplot will not necessarily adjust the plot's x/y limits to show them. You might have to do this yourself via [plt.xlim](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlim) and [plt.ylim](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylim).

Comment: Works perfectly, one thing to note; I discovered that the plt.arrow() returns an error when A and B are the same. After handling this, the function works properly. Thanks!