# Python plotting: visualize the order of the points in a plot

Tags: python, plot

I have a set of points, that I am plotting currently with `matplotlib`:

```
x_points = [82,92,90,90,83,74,36,36,36]
y_points = [67,67,66,73,71,69,56,57,57]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 160, 0, 120])
plt.show()
```

The goal is to indicate somehow in the plot their order. For example, a different color or a line between two points with an arrow, would indicate that (82,67) came before (92,67). How can this be done?

The generic goal is to plot a directed path on a x-y chart, given a set of input points.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [matplotlib.pyplot.arrow](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.arrow.html)

Please see this post:
[Draw arrows between 3 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120892/draw-arrows-between-3-points)

Comment: do you know if I can place the arrow in the middle of the line somehow?